# Something weird is happening with the GA4 parameter 'coupon'

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have a table in which I have the number of times that a coupon has been used. I wanted to add the dimension source/medium (to know where my traffic is coming from), and the total changes a lot. Wonder what could be going on here?

[screenshot 1, inicial table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McEIU.png)
[screenshot 2, second table with source/medium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYM6a.png)

*edit: I tried with another parameters of the purchase event and its happening the same